# sas programming: loop over a macro call

Tags: sas

I am new to sas and have the following macro call:
%test (input1=&lib._2015, input2=&lib.base, out=out_data_2016)

Now, I want a loop that in the next step the output_data_2016 are used as input1 and create a new out variable out_data_2017. The call then should look like:
%test (input1=out_data_2016, input2=&lib.base, out_data_2017).

Thanks in advance!

edit:
I have several years to observe (say 2010 till 2018). Then I need 9 macro calls:

`%test (input1=&lib._2014, input2=&lib.base, out=out_data_2015)
%test (input1=&lib._2015, input2=&lib.base, out=out_data_2016)
%test (input1=out_data_2016, input2=&lib.base, out_data_2017)` etc.

My hope is to create a loop, so that I need only one step, but I do not know why...

Comment: How is that a loop? It is just two macro calls.

Answer (score 1):

Please read through the SAS documentation, write some code and post a new question around what you tried.

> **[%DO, Iterative Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p0ri72c3ud2fdtn1qzs2q9vvdiwk.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)**
>
> Executes a section of a macro repetitively based on the value of an index variable.
>
> Type:
>   Macro statement
>
> Restriction:
>   **Allowed in macro definitions only**   (my emphasis)
>
> See also:
>   %END Statement
>
> …
>
> Syntax
>
> `%DO macro-variable=start %TO stop <%BY increment>;
>   text and macro language statements
>   %END;`